# Fill all my textboxes with the data from drop down list. LINQ TO ENTITY

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Im having troubles getting the data from the drop down list (Name, Last NAme, Country, Age etc populted in al my Texboxes.

I have a dropdown with the

```
 DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" <-- which is an INt.

var query = from i in context.AdeucaRegistro 
where i.ID ==Convert.ToInt16(DropDownListditarEstudiantes.SelectedValue) 
select i;
```

THis also does not work :(

Can someone help me getting all the data from the dropdown list into the textboxes with Linq?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you do not use convert in your linq statement it might cause an error

use something like

```
int id=Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListditarEstudiantes.SelectedValue); 

var query =( from i in context.AdeucaRegistro 
where i.ID ==id
select i).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked!!!!

 int selectedindez = Convert.ToInt16(DropDownListditarEstudiantes.SelectedValue);

            var query = (from i in contexto.AdeucaRegistro where i.RegistroID == selectedindez select i).FirstOrDefault();
            txtnombre.Text = query.Nombre;
            txtapelido.Text = query.Apellido;